# PHP imap retrieve emails from multiple folders and sort them

Tags: php, sorting, imap

I'm using imap_sort() function in PHP to retrieve and sort emails from inbox by date. That works fine.

```
$mbox = imap_open("{localhost:143}INBOX", "user_id", "password");
$result = imap_sort($imap, SORTDATE, 1);
```

However, I wonder whether there is a way to retrieve and sort emails from multiple folders, such as from INBOX and SENT, at the same time.

Is possible to do something like (basically):

```
$mbox = imap_open("{localhost:143}INBOX,SENT", "user_id", "password");
$result = imap_sort($imap, SORTDATE, 1);
```

Or it's the only solution to acquire results from one folder, then another and merge them, then sort them manually via standard PHP functions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IMAP only allows being 'connected' to one folder at a time, at least in the baseline specification.  You would have to either do it serially, or in parallel with two connections.

Comment: It appears so, that's why I checked if there's no other way. This makes imap_sort sadly useless for multiple folders. Thanks anyway!